# Tor gets stuck at "establishing an encrypted directory connection"

Tags: configuration, help, network-configuration

I unfortunately don't use Tor very much or know much about appropriate configurations, but recently I tried using Tor at my school and while trying to start up it got stuck on "establishing an encrypted directory connection" for ~8 minutes. I'm not entirely sure how long the process typically takes, but I dont believe it takes that long regularly. Should I be using different configurations for Tor (my current is the default one :p)

10/20/2016 21:40:49 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

10/20/2016 21:40:54 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or 
accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

10/20/2016 21:40:54 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

10/20/2016 21:40:54 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

10/20/2016 21:40:54 PM.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

10/20/2016 21:40:55 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

10/20/2016 21:40:55 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

10/20/2016 21:48:27 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

10/20/2016 21:48:27 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

10/20/2016 21:48:27 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

10/20/2016 21:48:28 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a victim of HTTPS/TLS/SSL attacks, try using Meek pluggable transport

UPDATE: A pluggable transport is an on-flight handler that masks Tor protocol and requests, so they don't look like themselves and look more like regular requests for another massively used protocol, like HTTPS, for example. The official ["how-to"](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/how-use-%E2%80%9Cmeek%E2%80%9D-pluggable-transport) is a good point to start

Comment: I unfortunately do not know what that is. Would you be willing to explain :o

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I tried using both azure meek and amazon meek (both of the available meeks) but neither one worked :(

Comment: My current connection unfortunately blocks pastebin so I can't post the error logs until later ;-;

Comment: http://hastebin.com/exewireruk.sql

Comment: Yes, your log indicates clearly that you need Meek pluggable transport. Try it

Comment: I did but when I tried it I had received that log

Comment: post your `torrc` please - the log seems to be without a Meek at all

Comment: I'm not sure what the torrc is but I tried all of the transportables and here are the logs for http://hastebin.com/hesapovunu.sql -- as shown each got stuck or simply didn't work at all

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow - 26 hours straight coding for now =) I'll post you an update as soon as I'll have some

Comment: alright np :DDD

Comment: It looks like you have either a very deep filtering, or some config mistake. Can you check/verify these pluggable transports from another connection and post the log too? if it will work - then it's a censorship issue for sure, if not - let us look deeper

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, but I've tried the pluggable transports all at home and they have all worked relatively well. However, whenever I try them at school with the filters it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @pleb nps! Please attach the logs and torrc configs - so I'll take a look